# Iterating through file and retaining data in list - Python

Tags: python, list, replace, iteration

I am iterating over lines in file-1 to get a list of [IDs, Names] and then I have file-2 which is a long string for which I would like to search for matching ID's which are in the format, (eg. (x66=92428482(x67:82482384285)),(x68=69464)) etc where IDs=66,67,68. I am trying to compare these two files and then replace the corresponding ID in file-2 with the Names from file-1.

Sorry if that sounds really confusing!

The first issue I am having is with iteration. I have the following so far:

```
def compare(file1, file2):
    next(identifiers)
    newick = newickfile.read()
    x = newick.split("homer")
    for bline in identifiers:
        id = bline.split()[-1]
        tf_name = bline.split()[3]
        data = [id, tf_name]
    print homer, data # issue 1
```

issue 1: This will only print the last line of data but when I ident it will print the string x too many times.

How can I compare both bits of data against each other without too many or too few iterations?

issue 2: I basically want to do something like this below to replace the ID with the name, would this be possible?

```
if data[0] in homer:
    homer.replace(data[1])
```

EDIT: What the input files look like (partial view as they are quite long)

File-1:

```
Cell type   TF  Rank    TF  Motif   P-value Motif_no
meso    cebpb   1   CEBP    VKATTGCGCAAT    1e-994  1
meso    cebpb   2   CEBP:AP1    TTGCAWCA    1.00E-36    2
meso    cebpb   3   CTCFL   GCCCCCTACTGG    1.00E-16    3
meso    cebpb   4   ETS1    GACTTCCTGM  1.00E-15    4
meso    cebpb   5   Zfx KAGACGCCGCGC    1.00E-15    5
meso    cebpb   6   Rfx5    TTAGWAACAGMC    1.00E-15    6
meso    cebpb   7   Zbtb12  GTTAGCGCGTTC    1.00E-13    7
meso    cebpb   8   MafA    CATGAGTCAGCC    1.00E-13    8
meso    cebpb   9   Sox2    ATTGCCTTGCAA    1.00E-13    9
meso    cebpb   10  Tcf4    CYTCTCTGCTTT    1.00E-12    10
```

etc...

File-2:

```
(homer6:0,(homer10:0,(homer4:0,(homer5:0,(homer7:0,((homer9:0.186282229002538,((((((homer1:0.129121013567978):0):0):0):0):0):0) etc...
```

Output wanted:

```
(Rfx5:0,(Tcf4:0,(ETS1:0,(Zfx:0,(Zbtb12:0,((Sox2:0.186282229002538,((((((CEBP:0.129121013567978):0):0):0):0):0):0) etc...
```

etc. for the corresponding motif numbers

Comment: can u clearly write file 1 content and file 2

Comment: do you mean can i print the contents?

Comment: ya, what u have given as example was not clear. if u provide clear view of file1 and file 2 it may help me to solve

Comment: Sorry i thought it might be. I have edited to include a view of these input files. I hope that makes it more clear, thank you!

Comment: I have also added the output I am trying to get, so you can see what I was trying to do

Comment: can u explain how homer99 is replaced by rfx5

Comment: sorry, that was just an example I did in haste, it would be replaced by whatever TF is at homer99. I will change the numbers so the examples are better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be as simple as reading through your `file1` and using `str.replace` on each line. Here is an example of using `str.replace`:

```
>>> foo = 'test'
>>> foo.replace('test', 'Hello World')
'Hello World'

# This will replace EACH instance of 't'.
>>> foo.replace('t', 'X')   
'XesX'

# This will return 'test' because foo doesn't contain 'bar'.
>>> foo.replace('bar', 'nothing')     
'test'
```

However, `str.replace` will not reassign the string its working on. So in the example above, `foo` still is `'test'`.

The below example should fit your purposes:

```
def compare(file1, file2):
    # This file SHOULD be one line. But just in case, do a loop anyways.
    homer = ''
    with open(file2, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            homer += line

    with open(file1, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            data = line.split()

            # -1 and 3 are indices where the Motif Num and TF are
            # located in the list.
            homer = homer.replace('homer{}'.format(data[-1]), data[3])
```

Comment: Would you be able to talk me through this please? What does "homer += line" do? And how does the last line work? Thank you :)

Comment: The line `homer += line` appends the lines of `file2` together. This is here just in case `file2` is longer than 1 line. The final line is replacing ANY instance of `homerXX` with your `TF` name. I'll update my answer to give an example of `str.replace`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, plus that explanation was very useful! Fantastic answer!! Plus I finally managed to get it working thanks again :)

Comment: Hey, I have just noticed that although it is replacing homer{} with a TF name, it is incorrect and I have no idea where some of the names have come from, eg. some of them are not even in my File-1 list like "Sox29". Could this be an iteration problem or is it not associating the TF with the homerID?

Comment: So some of the identifiers in `file2` aren't `homerXX`?

Comment: They are either homerX or homerXX with X being a number 0-9

Comment: Hmm, using your example input I got [your example output](http://codepad.org/vX4Ahiq5). I had to change a little bit due to the Python version used on codepad. However, functionally they are the same thing.